# Help me installing Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 on WindowsCE 5.0

Tags: sql-server-ce, windows-ce

I want to install Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 for Windows Mobile on a Windows CE 5.0 device

I installed int he desktop PC the file from
[Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12264)

Then I followed the instructions in
[How to: Install SQL Server Compact 3.5 on a Device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13kw2t64%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

But, at point 2, I don't find any
"\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Devices" directory.
Under "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\" dir there are only Desktop\ and Private\ dir.

How could Install SQL Server Compact 3.5 on WindowsCE 5.0? 
Thanks

Comment: Look in program files (x86)

Comment: Thank you very very much. I found it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Devices

Comment: That download link is now dead. Has anyone been able to find a copy of the device cab for SQL Server Compact?

Comment: I can assist, pls contact me directly (e-mail address is on my blog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 64-bit Microsoft OSes, many installations put files into a separate 32-bit Program Files folder, which is found at:

> C:\Program Files (x86)

Look there for the subfolder (Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition...) you're after.